# Eclipse RCPTT Hanging in Jenkins

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-rcp, ui-testing, eclipse-rcptt

I am trying to automate my Eclipse UI testing using Jenkins.
I have a Jenkins Windows slave where I have installed Eclipse RCPTT IDE. In Jenkins I am using this [script](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/runner/runner.cmd) with my information.

I have also narrowed it down to just run `java -jar C:/Users/myUsername/Desktop/rcptt/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar`

However, all I see in my Jenkins console is just a spinning icon.

When I run this from the command line on my Jenkins Windows slave, I see that my instance of RCPTT is opening correctly.

Has anyone configured their Jenkins to run RCPTT? Have you seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [user guide](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/maven/), you can use the Maven plug-in to automate the RCPTT test execution during Maven build:

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.rcptt</groupId>
<artifactId>rcptt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

Then, you can configure Jenkins to trigger the Maven command.